# Android development error - trying to stream audio using AsyncPlayer

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I have a problem trying to stream audio using the AsyncPlayer class in android.
(I'm working on this for a three days now - please help)

I have a stream of audio ("http://212.29.254.129:8920")
I'm trying to get it to play using the code below:

```
AsyncPlayer ap = new AsyncPlayer("myplayer");
ap.play(this, Uri.parse("http://212.29.254.129:8920"), false, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

It doesn't work... I don't have any idea why... The link works - I tested in in several different programs... Any ideas what it can be?
I have Internet permissions in the manifest, so that's not it...

Could it be in a format android specifically doesn't recognize?
If so how can I go around it?

I also tried to do this with MediaPlayer - there I get an IOException on function prepare.

Please please help! I'm out of ideas.

Comment: If there any message in the logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't support the AACP stream coming from that particular URL, so you are out of luck there. Your options are basically:

1. Finding a different shout/media/icecast of the same stream, that uses a different encoding. You could even approach them, or find a 3rd party that is willing to do live re-encoding of the stream  using tools like [EZStream](http://www.icecast.org/ezstream.php).
2. Trying to get the AACP to play on your android. One project for doing so can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/).

Comment: thank you very much!!!
I was racking my brain at this for hours...

I'll give that project u suggested a try...
thanks again!